# How to use static constructor reference with a three parameters Java 8 Function (without make TriFunction)?

Tags: java-8

I am currently playing with Java 8 and I found a problem with Function. I would like ton know if there is a way to use function reference (name::methode) with a Function with tree parameters without declare a new functional interface (i.e. TriFunction).

I tried with currying way, but it doesn't work.

I have three classes :

Person.class

```
public class Person {
    public enum Sex {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Sex gender;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Sex gender) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public Sex getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

PersonFactory

```
public class PersonFactory {
    public static Person create(String firstName, String lastName, String gender) {
        // Check firstName Parameter
        if(firstName == null || firstName.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The firstName argument expect to not be null or empty");
        }

        // Check lastName Parameter
        if(lastName == null || lastName.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The lastName argument expect to not be null or empty");
        }

        // Check gender Parameter
        if(gender == null || gender.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The gender argument expect to not be null or empty");
        } else {
            switch(gender) {
            case "M":
                return new Person(firstName, lastName, Sex.MALE);
            case "F":
                return new Person(firstName, lastName, Sex.FEMALE);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The gender parameter is supposed to be either 'M' for male or 'F' for Female");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CsVPersonParser

```
public class CsvPersonParser {
    public Person parseLine(String line, String separator, Function<String, Function<String, Function<String, Person>>> creator) {
        String[] separedLine = line.split(separator);
        String firstName = separedLine[0];
        String lastName = separedLine[1];
        String gender = separedLine[2];
        return creator.apply(firstName).apply(lastName).apply(gender);
    }
}
```

Here is my main class :

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String IMAGINARY_CSV_FILE_LINE = "Jean,Dupont,M";

        CsvPersonParser csvParser = new CsvPersonParser();
        csvParser.parseLine("blabla", ",", PersonFactory::create);
    }
}
```

The compilator show : The type PersonFactory does not define create(String) that is applicable here

It seems pretty logical. I have no solution. Is anyone can help me ?

Comment: As far as I know, that are the only two options, either create a new functional interface, or change your call to `PersonFactory::create` by `csvParser.parseLine("blabla", ",", f -> l -> g -> PersonFactory.create(f, l, g));`

Comment: Thank you, it helps me. I choose to create a new functional interface. It is clearly more readable. I wonder why there is no way to do it simple without to create new things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that what I wanted. However two other solutions is possible. Use a lambda instead of `PersonFactory::create` or create a new functional interface.

Here is the result :

New functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TriFunction<A, B, C, D> {
    public D apply(A a, B b, C c);
}
```

Add a function parseLine with my new functional interface

```
public class CsvPersonParser {

    // Currying style
    public Person parseLine(String line, String separator, Function<String, Function<String, Function<String, Person>>> creator) {
        String[] separedLine = line.split(separator);
        String firstName = separedLine[0];
        String lastName = separedLine[1];
        String gender = separedLine[2];
        return creator.apply(firstName).apply(lastName).apply(gender);
    }

    // New Functionnal interface style
    public Person parseLine(String line, String separator, TriFunction<String, String, String, Person> creator) {
        String[] separedLine = line.split(separator);
        String firstName = separedLine[0];
        String lastName = separedLine[1];
        String gender = separedLine[2];
        return creator.apply(firstName, lastName, gender);
    }
}
```

My main class with solutions

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String DATA_FILE_SEPARATOR = ",";
        final String FAKE_CSV_LINE = "Jean,Dupont,M";

        CsvPersonParser csvParser = new CsvPersonParser();
        Person person;

        // Use curryling style
        person = csvParser.parseLine(FAKE_CSV_LINE, DATA_FILE_SEPARATOR, f -> l -> g -> PersonFactory.create(f, l, g));
        System.out.println("Currying style : " + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName() + " " + person.getGender());

        // Use new functionnal interface
        person = csvParser.parseLine(FAKE_CSV_LINE, DATA_FILE_SEPARATOR, PersonFactory::create);
        System.out.println("TriFunction style : " + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName() + " " + person.getGender());

        // Use lambda style
        person = csvParser.parseLine(FAKE_CSV_LINE, DATA_FILE_SEPARATOR, (a,b,c) -> PersonFactory.create(a, b, c));
        System.out.println("Lambda style : " + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName() + " " + person.getGender());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder why there is no way to do it simple without to create new things.

Probably a tri function is quite complex. I suggest that you use a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to create a person.

The main reasons are, that you are not fixed on parameter ordering and you can extend your person. When you use a trifunction where all parameters are strings its often hard to say which parameter is the first/second/third. And when you want to add an address to a person it becomes more difficult to make it with generic classes like TriFunction.

My suggestion:

```
public interface PersonBuilder {
    PersonBuilder withFirstName(String firstName);

    PersonBuilder withLastName(String lastName);

    PersonBuilder withGender(String gender);

    Person create();
}
```

Concrete Implementation:

```
public class DefaultPersonBuilder implements PersonBuilder {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;

    @Override
    public PersonBuilder withFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public PersonBuilder withLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public PersonBuilder withGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Person create() {
        // Check firstName Parameter
        if (firstName == null || firstName.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The firstName argument expect to not be null or empty");
        }

        [... your implementation using the fields]
    }
}
```

Your parser method:

```
public Person parseLine(String line, String separator, PersonBuilder person) {
    String[] separedLine = line.split(separator);
    String firstName = separedLine[0];
    String lastName = separedLine[1];
    String gender = separedLine[2];
    return person.withFirstName(firstName).withLastName(lastName).withGender(gender).create();
}
```

Now you can change the argument order oder add new fields to person without creating a function with 10 parameters. The parser interface is simpler now, too.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. This design seems legit and probably better that what I did. However, the aim here was to use Java 8 features just to "play" with it. I did a +1 to your answer because it is really interesting and I like it. Unfortunately it doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Sorry that I missed your intent. On java 8 site of view it's still an interesting question.